# java - Swing Worker - passing many arguments

Tags: java, swing

I am passing many arguments (10 to be exact) into my class that extends Swing Worker so I was wondering if there is some way to create a helping class that would make my code more elegant and readable? task object is of the class. The code is working properly but I was wondering if I could make it more readable and more optimal if I decide to add more passing argument.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    SortThread task = new SortThread(a, brelem, sort, jButton1, brElemTextField,
            bubbleButton, selectionButton, insertionButton, jLabel3,
            konzola, startTime, stopTime, sekunde, jScrollPane2);
    task.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
            if ("progress".equals(e.getPropertyName())) {
                jProgressBar1.setValue((Integer) e.getNewValue());
            }
        }
    });
    task.execute();

}
```

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you should create a class for this. What have you tried and how isn't it working? Edit: and I second what @Jeff just said. Your question is way too broad, and also has nothing to do with Swing or SwingWorkers but just java in general.

Comment: So, to some general answers then: Try looking up design patterns. I'm not exactly a master of them, but off the top of my head the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) sounds useful.

Comment: Are you trying to make it easier to call for re usability or just trying to "pretty" up the code??

Comment: smells like a suboptimal, maybe even incorrect implementation of SwingWorker - better show what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

I can't really provide a good answer for this question, as I don't have much idea what it is you're trying to do. I **strongly** recommend looking up reading material on refactoring and design patterns, as experience with such techniques will help you always and forever.

As to the specific example: It seems like most of the arguments are UI controls - you could try making an object which contains your user interface objects, which you can then pass into the constructor in place of all of the objects. **EDIT:** You don't necessarily need to make a class of your own for this - a [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is also a possibility.

Alternatively, if you make `SortThread` an [inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), it can then have access to the fields of the parent, so you don't have to pass them in.

Of course, others with more experience will likely have more to say on the matter, but given that this question is so broad, I thought I'd throw in a couple of options anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing so many GUI components to your worker, have your view(s) register with the worker as a `PropertyChangeListener`. `SwingWorker` has a `firePropertyChange()` method that makes using the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pretty easy.